# How to stop a click event based on a server side JavaScript confirmation return?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have the following property I am calling in on a table being generated. For each record I have a delete button, but I wanted to add a Confirmation box to the click event. This codebase is pretty awkward in that almost all of the UI is being generated server side and I don't have much correct use of web forms best practices such as a clearly separated form and code behind.

I decided to add the JavaScript of a confirmation box to the attributes of the CssButton...is there a way to halt the process of the click if the user clicks 'Cancel' on the resulting client side confirm box. Could I somehow pass the javascript a bool, then get it back out and base my AddClickHandler on that bool? Thanks in advance for any help!

```
Private mDeleteButton As CssButton
Private ReadOnly Property DeleteButton() As CssButton
    Get

        If mDeleteButton Is Nothing Then
            mDeleteButton = New CssButton(ButtonImage.Cancel, "Delete")
            With mDeleteButton
                .Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript: (!confirm('Delete this future transaction?'))")
                .AddClickHandler(New EventHandler(AddressOf DeleteButton_Click))
                .CausesValidation = False
                .ID = String.Concat(Me.ID, "DeleteButton")
            End With
        End If
        Return mDeleteButton
    End Get
End Property
```

Comment: there is no `return` in th onclick. get rid of `javascript:`

Comment: `return false;` will cancel a click in JS.

Comment: In your javascript confirm function you can use stopPropagation to tell js that you've handled the event and that it doesn't need to bubble any further. If you want to stop the default behavior of an event (ie, onclick), you can use the preventDefault. This way, you would trigger the events you choose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code in the following manner. By adding the actual conditional statement and the result/action based on the condition within the attribute.

```
Private mDeleteButton As CssButton
Private ReadOnly Property DeleteButton() As CssButton
Get

    If mDeleteButton Is Nothing Then
        mDeleteButton = New CssButton(ButtonImage.Cancel, "Delete")
        With mDeleteButton
            .Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript: if(!confirm('Delete this future transaction?')) { return false; } else { //DO SOMETHING }")
            .AddClickHandler(New EventHandler(AddressOf DeleteButton_Click))
            .CausesValidation = False
            .ID = String.Concat(Me.ID, "DeleteButton")
        End With
    End If
    Return mDeleteButton
End Get
End Property
```